# Java FX WebView RejectedExecutionException

Tags: javafx

Please help.

My project throw java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException when i Close the application. 
Here My code:

```
JFXPanel panel;
Scene scene;
StackPane stack;
Text hello;
WebView webComponent;
WebEngine webEngine;

// CONSTANTS
private static final String[] JS_FILE_PATHS = { "scripts/c3.min.js", "scripts/d3.min.js", "scripts/drawC3Chart.js",
        "scripts/d3-context-menu.js" };
private static final String CSS_FILE_PATH = "stylesheets/c3.min.css";

// HARD CODE DATA TO TEST
private static final String TEST_DATA = "{\"colors\":[\"#70C047\",\"#4FCEFF\",\"#BB5FB8\",\"#FFB760\",\"#717ACC\",\"#EF7E5E\","
        + "\"#EBD24C\",\"#2C8CA8\",\"#BB9489\",\"#2BA85A\",\"#4F047A\",\"#008AFF\",\"#E5059E\",\"#1B4783\","
        + "\"#D5CC98\",\"#6C9949\",\"#0571C3\",\"#DC7514\",\"#85F29B\",\"#EAFF00\",\"#5E5860\",\"#148765\","
        + "\"#FC8B2B\",\"#C24D2C\",\"#4F15C2\"],\"categories\":[\"\"],\"data\":{\"rows\":[[\"Check Point | "
        + "FireWall-1\",\"Aladdin | eSafe Gateway Content Security\",\"NetScreen | Firewall/VPN\","
        + "\"Microsoft | ISA Server\",\"Check Point | VPN-1 & FireWall-1\",\"CISCO | PIX\",\"Unix | Unix\","
        + "\"Microsoft | ISA Server 2004\",\"cn Vendor | cn Product\",\"CISCO | ACNS\",\"Symantec | Endpoint Protection\","
        + "\"Unix | PF\",\"Netcontinuum | NC-1000\",\"NFR | CMS\",\"ISS | RealSecure\",\"Intruvert | IntruShield\",\"CISCO | ASA\","
        + "\"CISCO | Cisco NetFlow\",\"CISCO | Pix\",\"Check Point | cpmidu_update_tool\"],[\"6665\",\"6524\",\"2977\",\"2784\","
        + "\"1902\",\"1696\",\"1628\",\"1596\",\"1568\",\"1184\",\"1181\",\"1168\",\"1056\",\"983\",\"508\",\"420\",\"322\",\"300\","
        + "\"247\",\"228\"]],\"type\":\"bar\",\"groups\":[],\"chartType\":\"Bar\"},\"legend\":{\"show\":\"true\"},\"rotated\":"
        + "\"false\",\"xlabel\":\"Device Vendor | Device Product\",\"ylabel\":\"Total\",\"isStackData\":\"false\",\"tooltip\":"
        + "{\"show\":\"true\"},\"getContextMenuCmd\":\"cmd0\"}";

boolean wait = true;

public FXInSwing() {
    panel = new JFXPanel();
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webComponent = new WebView();
            webEngine = webComponent.getEngine();
            stack = new StackPane();
            scene = new Scene(stack, 500, 500);
            hello = new Text("Hello");

            // Load HTML page
            loadURLWebPage("views/d3Demo.html");

            // Load script files & CSS files
            executeScriptFiles(JS_FILE_PATHS);
            executeCSSFiles(CSS_FILE_PATH);

            // Execute below section after HTML page is
            // loaded.
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (scene != null && scene.getWindow() != null && scene.getWindow().isShowing())
                        // => Draw D3 Chart.
                        webEngine.executeScript("drawD3Chart(document.getElementById('visualisation')," + TEST_DATA + ", 1000, 500);");
                }

            });

            scene.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            hello.setFill(Color.WHEAT);
            hello.setEffect(new Reflection());

            panel.setScene(scene);
            stack.getChildren().add(webComponent);

            wait = false;
        }
    });
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(300, 300);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new FXInSwing();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Loading d3 chart function => Execute in Java Script
 */
public String d3ChartActionCommand(String cmdName, String data, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

    if (cmdName.equals("cmd0")) {
        return "[{data: [{cmd: \"cmd1\", name: \"Open Editor\"},{cmd: \"cmd2\", name: \"View Detail\"},{cmd: \"cmd3\", name: \"Configuration\"},],name: \"Choose Options\"}];";
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Load Script files
 * 
 * @param filePaths
 *            List of file paths
 */
private void executeScriptFiles(String[] filePaths) {
    for (String filePath : filePaths) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        try {
            String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
            webEngine.executeScript(content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Execute CSS File
 */
private void executeCSSFiles(String cssFile) {
    try {
        webEngine.setUserStyleSheetLocation(new File(cssFile).toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Load URL Web Page
 */
private void loadURLWebPage(String htmlFilePath) {
    File file = new File(htmlFilePath);
    try {
        webEngine.load(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

It throw an exception when i close the application. Tried to find more result but didn't help.
Please help me what should I do to fix this issue.
`